# UnitTest PageReference and If-else

Tags: apex

How can I test the If-else conditions and the pageReference in this visualforce controller extension ?  I have a good start to the unitTest below but not sure how to best test these other conditions.

Controller:

```
public with sharing class ParentChildExtensionDRIVERsample_New {

/*
This code supports the PROD_Audit_Auto_DriverSample_New visualforce page.
FUNCTION:
Receives parent ID (accID) aandd Sample ID passed via commandbutton or custom button on parent related list.
AccId must be passed via URL since we are instantiating a new object reccord which is not saved.
accID is needed to query parent fields that are used on the visualforce page for rendering.
SampleId is needed to load the related field on the object. 
A list object is used for the SOQL query to the parent. The result set is used in the visualforce page for setting control variables for rendering. 
The Sample ID is loaded into the related list field on the instanitated object to establish relationship when saved. 
*/

public Audit__c driver{get;set;}
Auto_Drivers__c record;
@TestVisible private ApexPages.StandardController controller;

String accId;
String sampleId;

public ParentChildExtensionDRIVERsample_New(ApexPages.StandardController standardController)
{
 this.controller = standardController;
//set sample to current record.
this.record = (Auto_Drivers__c)standardController.getrecord();

accID=ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('AccId');
sampleID=ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('sampleId');

List< Audit__c> drivers = [ select Id, Driver_Information__c, Age__c, Gender__c, Marital_Status__c, Named_Insured_Add_Driver__c, Occupation__c, Business_Use__c, MVR_Violations__c, Credit_Scoring__c                
           from Audit__c where Id = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('accId')]; 

//test if SOQL result is more than one, none or null. 
If(drivers.size() > 1) {
  ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'More than 1 record Found. Please contact the help desk with this error.'));
  }
else if(drivers.size() == 0) {
  ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'No records were found! Please contact the help desk with this error.'));
  }
else if(drivers.isEmpty() == true) {
  ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'No records were found! Value was null. Please contact the help desk with this error. '));
  }  
else {
  //do nothing
  driver = drivers[0];
  }

//Load the parent Name (ID) into the Audit field for newly instantiated object record. 
record.Auto_Audit_Sample_Policy__c = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('sampleId');
} 
//return user back to the audit sample to add new record.
public PageReference saveAndReturn()
    {
     controller.save(); 
     PageReference pr = Page.PROD_Audit_Auto_PolicySample_Open;
     pr.getParameters().put('id', sampleId);
     pr.setRedirect(true);
     return pr;
    }
}
```

***unitTest (at %65) ... need to test the above.***

```
@isTest
private class UnitTest_Driver {  
  //Test coverage for New Driver Creation (VF page) 
  static testmethod void testNewDriver() {
    List< Audit__c> drivers;

    Account acct = UtilityAudit.getAccount();
    insert acct;
    Audit__c audit = UtilityAudit.getAudit(acct.Id);
    insert audit; 
    Auto_Audit_Sample_Policy__c sample = UtilityAudit.getAuto_Audit_Sample_Policy(audit.Id);
    insert sample;
     Auto_Drivers__c driver = UtilityAudit.getAuto_Drivers(sample.Id);
     //driver.Driver_Birth_Year__c = '9999';
    insert driver;

    //initiate the VF page
    PageReference pageRef = Page.PROD_Audit_Auto_DriverSample_New;
    Test.setcurrentPage(pageref);

    //these parms are passed via custom button ?accId={!Audit__c.Id}&sampleId={!Auto_Audit_Sample_Policy__c.Id}
    Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().put('AccId', audit.Id);
    Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().put('sampleId', sample.Id);

    //create standard controller and extended controller instance
    ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.standardController(driver);
    ParentChildExtensionDRIVERsample_New testDriverPage = new ParentChildExtensionDRIVERsample_New(sc);

    //save the controller to get the URL
    String testPage = sc.save().getUrl();
    System.debug('TestPage result:' + testPage);
    System.debug('testDriverPage result:' + testDriverPage);    
    System.debug('pageRef result:' + pageRef);

    System.assertNotEquals(null, testPage);
    System.assertNotEquals(null, testDriverPage);     
    System.assertNotEquals(null, pageRef);

    // Verify that the success page displays
    //System.assertEquals('/apex/PROD_Audit_Auto_DriverSample_New', testPage);  


    String accID=ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('AccId');
    System.debug('accID: ' + accID);
    String sampleID=ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('sampleId');
    System.debug('sampleID: ' + sampleID);

    drivers = [ select Id, Driver_Information__c, Age__c, Gender__c, Marital_Status__c, Named_Insured_Add_Driver__c, Occupation__c, Business_Use__c, MVR_Violations__c, Credit_Scoring__c                
         from Audit__c 
         where Id = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('accId')]; 
    System.debug('Age : ' + drivers[0].Age__c );
    System.debug('Gender : ' + drivers[0].Gender__c );
    System.debug('Marital Status : ' + drivers[0].Marital_Status__c );    
    System.debug('resultSize : ' + drivers.size());
    System.debug('resultIsEmpty : ' + drivers.isEmpty());    

    System.assertEquals(true, drivers[0].Age__c );
    System.assertEquals(true, drivers[0].Gender__c );    
    System.assertEquals(true, drivers[0].Marital_Status__c);    
    System.assertEquals(1, drivers.size() ); 
    System.assertEquals(false, drivers.isEmpty() );


  }  
}
```

Comment: another best practice might be renaming your UtilityAudit class to something like TestFactory

Answer (score 1):

**Your parameters in the test method is AccId and in the controller it is looking for accId** this is a problem as it is case sensitive

**You can ignore my below code as you will NEVER have a size Greater than 1 as you are specifically filtering by ID so all you need to do is properly set the accID with correct case and insert one record and have another method insert no records**

**And you do not need both the empty AND 0 size as they are the same result**

For the if else statements:

Create several test methods each creating Audit record that will populate the list to the desired size:

for example

```
private static test method void testSizeONE(){
   //Normal setup code

   //Create 1 audit record with the appropriate values to generate a list in the controller of size 1

  //Instantiate the controller ParentChildExtensionDRIVERsample_New

   //Also you could create additional records with none having the appropriate values (to ensure the right records are being pulled in)

  //Instantiate a new controller ParentChildExtensionDRIVERsample_New
}

private static test method void testSizeZERO(){

    //normal setup code

   //Create NO audit record with the appropriate values to generate a list in the controller of size 0
   //Instantiate the controller ParentChildExtensionDRIVERsample_New    

   //Also create additional records with none having the appropriate values (to ensure the right records are being pulled in)
  //Instantiate a new controller ParentChildExtensionDRIVERsample_New

}
```

Always remember to properly assert for desired results

For the page reference

```
//Set up data to get the desired sampleID in the page reference
//Where con = your controller in the test method

     Pagereference pr = con.saveAndReturn();  
     system.assertEquals(DESIREDSAMPLEID,pr.getParameters().get('id');
```

This should provide you with the framework to properly test you controller

Comment: to echo Eric's remarks here; a best practice would be to declare `@TestVisible private static final String accIdParm = 'accid';` in the controller and then reference that variable in the testmethod when setting test page parms - this way, you don't mess yourself up with typos or case issues

Comment: Thanks for the response. I removed the IsEmpty reference, less code to test. Also, used your Pagereference test which bumped me up to 95% coverage. How can I test assertions using the message results of :else if(drivers.size() == 0) {
  ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'No records were found! Please contact the help desk with this error.'));
  }

Comment: @rickmac - Grab the page messages and test that the message contains / equals the desired value. Read up on the apex pages methods